# Prime patterns in different form representation need attention

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory

For a prime $p$ $(p \ge7)$ can be expressed in the foam of $2a$ + $b$, where $a$ and $b$ again primes. For instance,

$7 = 2(2) + 3$,

$11 = 2(2) + 7$,

$13 = 2(5) + 3$,

$17 = 2(7) + 3$,

$19 = 2(7) + 5$,.. and so on…

Can we generalize these patterns and existence, if infinitely many such $2a + b$ exists?
Awaiting the reply...
Praseen*

Comment: I suspect this is an unsolved problem.

Comment: Have you written a program to test your hypothesis at least for $p < 10000000$ ?

Comment: Lemoine's/Levy's conjecture http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lemoine%27s_conjecture generalizes this.

Comment: @GerryMyerson this is not unsolved type peoblem

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan! I do not have any program to testing. will you do for me?

Comment: @Zander! you are correct. but, I am not making equally statements like wiki given. my one is quite different.

Comment: Not right now, but I will do it in several hours when I have free time... if nobody esle does before that.

Comment: primepeople, are you saying you know for a fact that this is true? How?

Comment: @ArmenTsirunyan! Now some saveral hours are passed. please do it

Answer (score 1):

It was recently proved that there are integers $k$ such that there are infinitely many pairs of primes $p$, $q$ with $p-q=2k$. If any of the numbers $k$ for which this has been proved are prime, that settles the question, as it shows there are infinitely many primes $p$ of the form $2k+q$ with $k$ and $q$ prime.

Comment: Zhang's proof gives an explicit finite set in which $k$ must lie but doesn't yield any one explicit value of $k$.  (Right?) So we're close, but we're not there yet.

Comment: @Gerry Myerson! could you share the proof of your statement 2k + q = p.

Comment: @PeteL.Clark Dear Pete, Zhang proved that there are infinitely many pairs of primes whose difference lies in the set $\{1,\dots,7\cdot 10^6\}$. Let this set of pairs of primes be denoted by $A$. Let $A_k$ denote the set of pairs of primes whose difference is exactly $k$. We then have: $A=\bigcup_{k=1}^{7\cdot 10^6} A_k$. Since $A$ is infinite and the finite union of finite sets is finite, it follows that at least one $A_k$ is infinite. Maybe I'm confused but I think this is right ...

Comment: @PeteL.Clark ... In fact, in light of this, I sometimes wonder why Zhang's theorem isn't stated as: **Theorem** For some natural number $k$, there are infinitely many prime pairs with difference equal to $k$. Somehow this formulation seems more elegant than the predominant formulation (on the internet) of the same statement with "at most k" rather than "equal to k". If you'd like to remember the bound, then perhaps we could augment the statement by saying: $k$ can be taken to be at most $7\cdot 10^7$. Regards,

Comment: @Amitesh: you're right and that's what Gerry is saying.  What I'm saying is that the argument doesn't allow you to **explicitly name** any one $k$, so we can't know yet whether $k$ can be taken to be prime.  (About the reformulation: to an analytic number theorist you've said the same thing twice.  I can't speak for the internet!)

Comment: @Pete Oh, I see. Yes, that's certainly true.

Comment: Hello! can you share the proof more precisely or give the reference of the proof of Zhang's